# trying to make an arraylist gives me this error

Tags: java, generics, syntax-error

I am getting an error at this line in the code below:

```
listofmembers.add(Member);
```

Trying to make an arraylist but gives me this error could someone please help me fix it 
thank you i'm trying to make my library class save my members and books so that I could print them as a list

```
public class Library
{
    private ArrayList<Member>listofmembers;
    public Library()
    {
        listofmembers = new ArrayList<Member>();
    }
    public void storeMember(String Member)
    {
        listofmembers.add(Member);
    }
    public int numberOfMembers()
    {
        return Member.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your main() method also. Also, please list the error.

Comment: And please take more care when formatting your code - you've got huge amounts of vertical whitespace and inconsistent indentation.

Comment: Your method signature `public void storeMember<>(Member)` carries invalid Java syntax.

Comment: Also, somewhere Austin Powers loves reading `Member.size();`

Comment: I have edited your question for two reasons: 1. code formatting, and 2. your code wasn't the same as your error screenshot

Comment: @rajah9 As you can see in the screenshot, he is using BlueJ. Normally there is no `main` method in these projects.

Comment: Thank you, Andy, for posting and formatting the code. @Tom, Thank you for pointing this out. The screen shot has been edited away, but I couldn't see it from behind my corporate firewall.

Comment: @beltric Please don't edit your question to extend it with a totally new one. You should ask a separate question instead, and choose and accept any answer below that was given to your initial problem.

Comment: Ok sorry i'm new to this not really sure how it works I will post new thank you everyone

Comment: No problem. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to add a `String` to an `ArrayList<E>` of type `Member`. That won't work. Either change your array list to be `ArrayList<String>`, or add a `Member` to `listofmembers`.

It is most likely that declaration `public void storeMember(String Member)` is meant to be:

```
public void storeMember(Member member)
{
    listofmembers.add(member);
}
```

Also, `numberOfMembers` should return `listofmembers.size()`, not `Member.size()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two syntax errors:

1.
You are missing a parameter *name* (and remove the `<>`):

```
public void storeMember(Member member) {
   listofmembers.add(member);
}
```

2.
Return the size of the *list* (not the class?):

```
public int numberOfMembers() {
    return listofmembers.size();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont init your ArrayList like this: `list = new ArrayList<Member>();`
But like this: `list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. It is just an improvement in code style for users of JDK7 (or above)

Comment: Ohh, okey. Wasent sure either.